# What is the meaning of [[:space:]] in bash?

Tags: bash, syntax

I just came across a bash script. What does `[[:space:]]` mean in a bash script?
Why the double colon?

Answer (score 44):

It is, indeed, in the bash manual, but it helps to know what you're looking for, which *isn't* helpful if you don't know what you're looking at. If you searched for `[[` you'd get distracted by the `[[ expression ]]` conditional expression section. Additionally, searching for `:space:` lands you in two examples under the same section. You might follow the breadcrumb in that example:

> For example, the following will match a line (stored in the shell variable line) if there is a sequence of characters in the value consisting of any number, including zero, of space characters, zero or one instances of ‘a’, then a ‘b’:
>
> ```
> [[ $line =~ [[:space:]]*?(a)b ]]
> ```

... from which you could piece together that the `[[:space:]]` portion corresponded to "space characters", but you could be forgiven for thinking that it was *only* a literal space character and not a whole class of characters, which is what it represents.

If you (happen to?) search for the string `" space"` (that is, a space followed by the word "space") in the [online bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html), there are "only" about 32 matches to go through. About the tenth one will be here:

> Within ‘[’ and ‘]’, character classes can be specified using the syntax [:class:], where class is one of the following classes defined in the POSIX standard:
>
> ```
> alnum   alpha   ascii   blank   cntrl   digit   graph   lower
> print   punct   space   upper   word    xdigit
> ```
>
> A character class matches any character belonging to that class.

Which would then take you to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) where you might search for the term "character class" and find

[wctype, wctype_l - define character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wctype.html), which gets you as far as:

> The wctype() [CX] [Option Start]  and wctype_l() [Option End]  functions shall determine values of wctype_t according to the rules of the coded character set defined by character type information in the current locale [CX] [Option Start]  or in the locale represented by locale, [Option End]  respectively (category LC_CTYPE).

If you then followed the [setlocale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) link, you'd  finally get to your real answer, in the [Locale section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07):

> **space**
>
> Define characters to be classified as white-space characters.
>   In the POSIX locale, exactly `<space>, <form-feed>, <newline>, <carriage-return>, <tab>, and <vertical-tab>` shall be included.
>
> In a locale definition file, no character specified for the keywords upper, lower, alpha, digit, graph, or xdigit shall be specified. The `<space>, <form-feed>, <newline>, <carriage-return>, <tab>, and <vertical-tab>` of the portable character set, and any characters included in the class blank are automatically included in this class.

Comment: Easier to find the manual match with `LESS=+'/Within \[ and \],' man bash` instead of 32 `n`ext commands :-).

Comment: @Isaac I think the point is to teach the man how to fish. That said, I did not know about `less +"$cmd"`, so thanks for that.

Comment: Indeed, I answered given the OP's perspective; they could be forgiven for not picking up that the outer `[]` are independent of the inner `[]`. I tried (!) to find a way from the question to the answer without knowing *too much* about what the answer was, although it took some lucky guessing :)

Answer (score 23):

It is not only for Bash, It is part of POSIX notation.

**What is POSIX?**

> POSIX or "Portable Operating System Interface for uniX" is a collection of standards that define some of the functionality that a (UNIX) operating system should support. One of these standards defines two flavors of regular expressions.

**POSIX Bracket Expressions**

> POSIX bracket expressions are a special kind of character classes. POSIX bracket expressions match one character out of a set of characters, just like regular character classes.

**Standard POSIX**

```
[[:alnum:]]   Alphanumeric characters
[[:alpha:]]   Alphabetic characters
[[:blank:]]   Space and tab
[[:cntrl:]]   Control characters
[[:digit:]]   Digits
[[:graph:]]   Visible characters (anything except spaces and control characters)
[[:lower:]]   Lowercase letters
[[:print:]]   Visible characters and spaces (anything except control characters)
[[:punct:]]   Punctuation (and symbols).
[[:space:]]   All whitespace characters, including line breaks
[[:upper:]]   Uppercase letters
[[:xdigit:]]  Hexadecimal digits
```

**None Standards**

```
[[:ascii:]]   ASCII characters
[[:word:]]    Word characters (letters, numbers and underscores)
```

**legacy syntax (can someone find reference to these?)**

```
[[:<:]]       Start of Word 
[[:>:]]       End of Word
```

You can find more info here: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)

Comment: `[[:ascii:]]`, and `[[:word:]]` are not POSIX classes (they seem to be `bash`-specific), and I can't find `[[:<:]]` nor `[[:>:]]` either. A better reference may have been https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html

Comment: Yeah, `[[:ascii:]]`, and `[[:word:]]` are none standard POSIX classes. for `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, I cannot find any references, but it is same is `\b`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Comment: Postgres defines the use of `[[:<:]]` and claims that: [This is an extension, compatible with but not specified by POSIX 1003.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS)

Comment: `[[:<:]]` is in FreeBSD too, with the same caveat as PostgreSQL has: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Comment: And `[[:ascii:]]` and `[[:word:]]` of course work in Bash in pattern matching, but not in regular expressions (at least on my system, I think Bash uses the system's regex library). Bah.

Answer (score 10):

In regular expressions and filename globs/shell patterns, the `[...]` construct matches any one character of those listed within the brackets. Within those brackets, a number of named standard character *character classes* can be used. One of those is `[:space:]`, which matches whitespace characters (like `\s` in Perl regexes). See e.g. [Pattern Matching in Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

So, `[[:space:]]` is a part of a regular expression or pattern match, one that matches just whitespace.

E.g. a pattern match (standard shell, not Bash-specific):

```
case $var in 
    *[[:space:]]*) echo "'$var' contains whitespace";;
esac
```

or a regex (Bash):

```
if [[ $var =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then
    echo "'$var' contains whitespace"
fi
```

Note that even though bracket expressions `[...]` work the same in regular expressions and shell patterns, they are generally very much *not* the same.
(`case` and `[[ string == pattern ]]` use pattern matches, `[[ string =~ regex ]]` uses regexes.)

Regular expressions also aren't shell-specific, they're used in e.g. `awk` and `sed` too, and are described in e.g. the [Linux man page `regex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html)